# How to translate a CURL command into a Rails POST request for an OAuth token?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, oauth-2.0, instagram

I am a web-development student and am trying to work with the [Instagram API](http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/).  I have never had to deal with OAuth before.

So far I can get the code from the user authorizing me to use their Instagram credentials but the POST request to get the actual token eludes me.  I am trying to use [Typhoeus](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus) for server side API requests but where I get hung up is in translating curl commands into usable rails controller script.

The Instagram API recommends the following curl command:

```
curl \-F 'client_id=CLIENT-ID' \
-F 'client_secret=CLIENT-SECRET' \
-F 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
-F 'redirect_uri=YOUR-REDIRECT-URI' \
-F 'code=CODE' \https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token
```

and here is my attempt at a Typhoeus POST request:

```
request = Typhoeus::Request.new(
  "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token",
  method: :post,
  :body => {:client_id => CLIENT_ID,
              :client_secret => CLIENT_SECRET, 
              :grant_type => "authorization_code", 
              :redirect_uri => CALLBACK_URL, 
              :code => code}
  )
@results = JSON.parse((request.run).body)
```

And I get the following error when I try and log @results:

```
{"code"=>400, "error_type"=>"OAuthException", "error_message"=>"You must provide a client_id"}
```

I have all the info that the API needs, I just don't know how to arrange it correctly... And yes, all of the constants are defined.  Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the [instagram-ruby-gem](https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem) to make requests to the Instagram API. You'll find it much easier than using Typhoeus.

Comment: The project I'm working requires that we use rails.  So no Sinatra for me!  Thanks though, already looked into it.

Comment: You should be able to use with Rails. :) See this article: http://blog.ajmalafif.com/instagram-gem-with-rails/

Comment: Somehow I actually just managed to make it work with the above code.  Im sure I didn't change anything, but @results is now full of JSON.  I'm going to leave this question open until I figure out what I actually did to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I solved my own question.  The above Typhoeus script works just fine, with lots of JSON love for everyone.

I think I might have been having obscure session issues with my rails server when @results kept coming back as nil.

I wish I had a more specific answer as to why this wasn't working earlier, but I'll keep my nose to the ground as I move forward and hopefully have a more satisfying conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in powershell
finally, I put the client_id and code in the query string also. then it works. I mean something like this:

"https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=CLIENT_ID&code=code"